# saving date and time of user response in django model field

Tags: django

i am making this app in django where on a particular html template if the user selects a particular response by clicking on it, the date and time at which the user clicked that particular response is stored in my database.

part of models.py

```
class userresp(models.Model):
    rid=models.Integerfield(unique=True,default=0)
    uid=models.Foreignkey(user,to_field='uid',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
resp=models.ForeignKey(elementsound,to_field='csid',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date=models.DateTimeField()
    time=models.DateTimeField()
```

so how do i store that? and what will be the extra parameters in the DateTimeField of both?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the what you require inside a View by overriding the post() method.

To store the user's response time, you can make use of django's builtin **timezone** module.
So you just need to do:

```
  from django.utils import timezone

  date_and_time = timezone.now()
```

**timezone.now()** returns the system date and time of the server.
And by the way, you don't need two '**DateTimeField**'s to store the date and time. One is enough, it can store both the date and time.

Otherwise you can just get the current date and time at the time of userresp object creation.

```
class userresp(models.Model):
    rid=models.Integerfield(unique=True,default=0)
    uid=models.Foreignkey(user,to_field='uid',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resp=models.ForeignKey(elementsound,
                           to_field='csid',
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_and_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: is it this way: date_and_time=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now()) or just date_and_time=timezone.now() in model

Comment: Yes you're right. I was just depicting how to get the current date and time above. `date_and_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` is enough for automatically storing the date and time in the field.  I will update my answer